# Laravel - Task Scheduling(The system cannot find the path specified.)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

When I run :

```
php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1
```

It gives me an error

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

The tutorial says that /path/to/artisan is where your project folder is located.
My project folder is located in

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/project/
```

But when I run :

```
php C:/xampp/htdocs/project/ schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1
```

or

```
php C:/xampp/htdocs/project/artisan schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1
```

It gives me the same error

Comment: You are probably trying to run a command usually run from unix cron from a windows console. Try this: `C:/path/to/php.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/project/artisan schedule:run` . If you need to scedule a cron job, this might help: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/running-schedulerun-on-windows/replies/56348

Comment: The scheduled task run once, but not everyMinute. I'll try to look through that link. Thanks

Comment: Where you able to find a soluction?, I am having a similar issue, however my error is out-file : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\dev\null'.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
php C:/xampp/htdocs/project/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/null` directory doesn't exist in windows, hence, this error comes out.

You can try this temporary solution just to get rid of the error.

Look for `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event.php` file and scroll to line 83.  Change the `$output = /dev/null` to `$output = 'NUL 2>&1'`. Then run the cron again.

I hope someone finds this helpful. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

mainly this comes when you try laravel jobs testing in your local.
first, deploy code in live and try again.